# How to ban PhpStorm from jumping to another line automaticly?

Tags: javascript, phpstorm

When I type 'title' in JavaScript file, PhpStorm jumped to another line automatically. So I can not type on the specific line.

## Like pictures below:

[image: type "t"]

[image: jumped automatically]

How to block it?

Comment: can't reproduce. Notebook?

Comment: I can not type any words

Comment: What is your PhpStorm version?

Comment: Version:PHPStorm 2016

Comment: Can you be **a bit** more specific please -- full version including build number (Help | About). The behaviour you have described (editing one line and text gets altered in completely different line) is very unexpected .. and something remotely related was fixed in 2016.1.1. The latest stable version is 2016.1.2.

Comment: PhpStorm 2016.1
Build #PS-145.258, built on March 16, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_60-b27 x86
JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM by Oracle Corporation

Comment: Well ... upgrade to the latest **2016.1.2** version and see if it works there or not.

Comment: Yeah,I downloaded from PhpStorm's website.It is the lastest version.Problems still exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug, [WEB-21643](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-21643) is fixed in **2016.1.3**

Comment: OK,Thank you.But your link is WebStorm,mine is PhpStorm

Comment: It's a bug,and is fixed in 2016.1.2.Thank you